# Upgrading CodeIgniter 1.7.2 to 3.1.6 most efficient way

Tags: php, codeigniter

is there any way to upgrade CodeIgniter 1.7.2 to 3.1.6 Directly. I have a project using CodeIgniter 1.7.2 and I tried to debug all errors on it, but they error keeps displaying one after another. what is the most efficient way to do this.

PS: site is too large to refactor code to 3.1.6.

Comment: You either fix all the errors or you stay on an earlier version. I don't know what kind of shortcut you think there's going to be? There's no automatic upgrader.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for an automatic upgrader. I am looking for an efficient way to upgrade it without much errors or the right way to upgrade it. I am migrating the site to a hosting with higher version of PHP which I need to match with the version of CodeIgniter.

Comment: Since we don't know what the errors are it's difficult to say if there would be any workarounds. But the errors are, I would guess, likely to be because the code isn't compatible with the newer version of PHP, rather than anything specific about any upgrade process. Did you follow a particular process? As I said though, if there's an error you need to fix it. Simple as that really.

Comment: Why 3.1.6? The latest of Version 3.x is 3.1.11 with a lot of fixes from earlier 3.x versions. You don't mention the php version you plan to use. I'd recommend to install a new 3.1.1. version on your localhost and then tranfer your views, controllers and models, as well as any libraries and other custom stuff... debugging constantly, whenever you add anew file. Good luck with that

Comment: I need at least version 3.x to migrate it. any version will do. the catch is, on early versions of codeigniter, the structures of MVC on on the same folder named modules. I'm not sure if this is the real structure of CI at that time that's why I'm having a really hard time planning how to migrate.